# LINQ with Include and Where not showing desired results

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a linq statement that combines Residents and Requests table like so

```
var resident = await _context.Resident
.Include(s => s.Requests)                
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

The problem is that all requests show up even those that are not related to the Resident.

I have tried adding a Where statement but still getting all requests.

```
var resident = await _context.Resident
.Include(s => s.Requests)
.Where(s =>s.UserID == "f7c6ceef-663f-48af-9a84-b0a3d2a97601")
.FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

For reference this is the Resident Model Class

```
public class Resident
    {
        public Resident()
        {
            this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Street Address")]
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Postal Code")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Number of Cameras")]
        public int CameraQty { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

        public string Latlng { get; set; }        

        public ICollection<Camera> Cameras { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Request> Requests { get; set; }



    }
```

This is the Request Model Class

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVC_NeighbourhoodCamera.Models
{
    public class Request
    {
        public Request()
        {
            this.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int ResidentID { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        public DateTime StartDateTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndDateTime { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Details { get; set; }
        public Boolean Completed { get; set; }
        public Boolean Active { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }


        public Resident Resident { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your model classes (Resident + Request)

Comment: Please see my updated question with model classes. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You do not have foreign key properly set in Resident->Requests one-to-many relationship.

Fix your `Request` class as following by adding `ForeignKeyAttribute` (+make migration and run it in to the db):

```
public class Request
{
    //Other properties
    ..
    public int ResidentID { get; set;}
    ForeignKey["ResidentID"]
    public Resident Resident { get; set;}   
}
```

More info can be found i.e [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx).

Comment: My understanding was that naming ResidentID as such automatically makes it a foreign key. I can confirm that ResidentID is a foreign key when I inspect it in SQL

Comment: Is it possible that foreign key is created in modelBuilder/DbContext -class? Foreign key is created automatically if names matches exactly (in that case`ResidentId` should also be name of Primary key in `Resident` class but is `Id`). Check out this link: https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Hmm... I see your point. Let me explore more and see if the problem lays there. Thank you

Comment: Ok good. If foreign keys are properly set, then I have no idea what is reason for problem. If problem is not missing foreign key I can remove this answer later.. please let me know.. thanks!

Comment: I'd be suspicious of this too. Nothing in the model looks that out of place to suggest otherwise. If this is still an issue I would suggest running an SQL Profiler against the database, and with the help of a breakpoint on that statement, capture the SQL that is being run by EF when that statement runs. Personally I never rely on EF's "conventions" and always opt for explicit relationship and key mapping. Sometimes it just gets "weird" :)